# Allow us to decline custom chat flags

Tags: feature-request, chat, flags, moderator-tools, declined-flags

Recently I've noticed a few custom flags (mostly coming from a particular room), where a user custom flags a message just to get the attention of a site-specific mod. (e.g "reopen this question plz", "explain why this was closed", etc)

Maybe the time has come to add on a "decline flag" option for these? Basically an option which  will allow the mod to enter some text. When the flag is declined, the user will get a popup notification telling him about it (and a link to the faq page about chat flags).

Point is, custom flags are private. So I can't simply ping the guy in his room "Oy! That's not what flags are for!". I have to create a separate room for it, and that seems like a waste :/

As a side note: Are we allowed to chat ban users for misusing the flag system if they continue to do so after receiving warnings? (just a thought)

Comment: It's probably better to just enter the room, advise people _not_ to do that without naming anyone specifically, then _pin_ it.

Comment: Of course people can feel free to ignore that if they want a moderator examining their account in great detail ..... (emphasis on `......`)

Comment: @TimPost: Good idea, though in my experience these users do the following: Ping a mod. Wait an hour for a reply, then flag and leave. I've got no way of telling if the user is still listening :(